# Is there a way to transform "found" to stand for "things which have been found"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I can think of use *discoveries* as the *things which have been found*. Is there a way to do that by transforming the word *found*? Like we can say "things which belong to you" as "your belongings".

Comment: 对不起, I think you might mean "things which have been found" and "things which belong to you"

Comment: Updated. Does the word *which* matter?

Comment: yes. "Things have been found" is a statement. "Things which have been found" is a noun-phrase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on the context:

*findings* usually refers to things found through investigation:

> **finding** *n.* A conclusion reached as a result of an
> inquiry, investigation, or trial

*discoveries* implies either facts that one has become aware of, things found by accident or chance, or things found as a result of a process (such as oil discovered by exploration)

> **discover** *v.*
>
> 1. Find (something or someone) unexpectedly or in the course of a search
> 2. Become aware of (a fact or situation)
>
> **discovery** *n.* A person or thing discovered

*find* can be used as a noun in some contexts:

> **find** *n. (pl. finds)* A discovery of something valuable, typically something of archaeological interest

None of these words would really be appropriate for things found in the normal course of life, for example I keep a shoebox of interesting things I have found on the ground out-and-about.  It would not really be correct to call them my findings, nor my discoveries, *things I found* is probably the best word / phrase to use in this context.

Comment: Yes _findings_ is not used to talk about objects.  The noun *find* can be used, but typically for items of archaeological significance not for everyday things.

Comment: @z7sg ahh yes another good one.. I think the plural of that noun is actually *finds*. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Actually, "findings" is often used in a jewelry/beading context (my girlfriend's influence here...) [to describe the structural members of jewelry.](http://www.firemountaingems.com/findings.asp)

Answer (score 3):

For things, *findings* is the correct word, especially in research.

For abandoned children, the word is *[foundling](http://www.bbc.co.uk/history/british/victorians/foundling_01.shtml)*

Answer (score 2):

Try [findings](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/findings). The infinitive for "found" is "find", thus word "findings" is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I was thinking *foundings*, which is wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found objects

Miscellaneous discovered objects included in an art piece or exhibited as an art piece are known as ‘found objects’.

A found object is also known as an objet trouvé, from the French for found object.

Example:

Contemporary Collage
of "found" cigarette butts,
by Dan Mountford.

http://www.visual-arts-cork.com/definitions/found-objects.htm